# Get Elastic documents which have not more than a specific number of children

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, parent-child, nest

This NEST-query selects documents without children:

```
.Bool(b => b
    .MustNot(q => q
        .HasChild<SolutionElasticModel>(c => c
            .Query(cq => cq
                .MatchAll()))));
```

What will be the NEST request that selects documents that have fewer children (including no children at all) than a certain number?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with indexing child count in the document itself:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int NestedDocsCount => NestedDocs?.Count;
    public List<NestedDoc> NestedDocs {get;set;}
}
```

and then use a regular [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-range-query.html#query-dsl-range-query)(in [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-filter-context.html#CO197-6)):

```
{
    "range": {
        "nestedDocsCount": {
            "gte": 10,
            "lte": 20
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case that is not a solution due to increasing a version of the document each time when its children are updated.